# Can RPi dynamically switch between HDMI and NTSC output, or does this require a re-boot?

Tags: hdmi, composite-video

I am developing an application that will use the NTSC output.  It displays mostly numeric data (preferably in various font sizes and colors) and a couple of graphic analog-style "meters".  The desire is to get the display to be easily readable on an NTSC display (7").  Unfortunately, this is a hard requirement, so I have to use a 7" NTSC Monitor.  However, the 7" display is difficult to navigate and even more difficult to read when driving the OS and code editors, so an HDMI monitor is preferred while I am writing code.  I'd like to be able to quickly switch between HDMI and NTSC to see how the application looks on the NTSC monitor.

Answer (score 2):

at the terminal you can change display.

```
tvservice -c NTSC 4:3
```

should set into NTSC mode 4:3 aspect ratio.

You can switch the other way see http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=5851

`tvservice` will show options