# Switching between monitors

Tags: raspbian

I have a little monitor connected through the 40 pins on my raspberry pi, but because the 
monitor is so tiny I would like to be able to switch between the small one and my big 
monitor that uses hdmi.

I've tried looking around on the internet and I could not find anything.

And is possible i would like to be
alle to change it without edditing a file but just by using commands.

So how do i do that??

Comment: You may be able to use `tvservice` http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/27199/8697

Comment: Edit in the output from `xrandr`.